# Create dummy instances of custom entity with dummy field data?

Tags: entities

My module defines a custom entity type and bundle and adds fields to the bundle programatically. Now, I need to create a bunch of dummy data to test the interface. I'm working with various combinations of entity_get_controller()->create(), entity_metadata_wrapper()->save(), field_attach_submit(), etc. and I have been able to fill the entity base table with new rows. The problem is that the generated entities aren't loaded with:

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'my_entity_type');
```

I'm not surprised that the query doesn't return my new entities because I haven't found a place to specify bundle for the dummy entities and I haven't figured out how to generate default or random field data. How do I specify the bundle for my new entities and how can I generate valid random field data for date, taxonomy_term_reference and integer fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My created entities were not listed by the EntityFieldQuery above because of this issue: [Make EntityFieldQuery::fieldOrderBy include NULL field values](http://drupal.org/node/1662942)

My new entities did not include a date field that was used to sort the table. So, the table didn't include the null-field entries.

I didn't figure out how to specify the bundle for my new entities but there is only one bundle defined, so it is the default. I'm still interested in a function that would be able to create random field data valid for each type of field. Heading over to look at Devel module for that function.